# How to set a limit in a for loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, while-loop

I have to create a program to calculate the average of each students' scores. I managed to do that but how can I limit the score to be only between 0 to 100? I've searched other questions and many shows to put while statement. The problem is that I don't know where to add the while. So here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageScore {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x; // Number of students
    int y; // Number of tests per student
    int Score = 0; //Score of each test for each student
    double Average = 0; //Average score
    double Total = 0; //Total score

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of students: ");
    x = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of test scores per student: ");
    y = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int z = 0; z < x; z++)
    {           
    System.out.println("Student " + (z + 1));
    System.out.println("------------------------");

    for (int g=0; g < y; g++)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter score " + (g + 1) + ":  ");

        Total += new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        Total += Score;
        Average = (Total/y);
    }       

    System.out.println("The average score for student " + (z + 1) + " is " + Average);
    System.out.println("                      ");

    Total= 0;
    }

    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

If there is any other ways please do state. Thanks in advance.

Comment: suppose you need validation on the entered test score to be 0-100. Then no need for while just put a if else clause to check the entered score is in the range.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I'm not sure where to put the if else

Comment: you have to put it before asking for input of scores. set aside quesstion,  why are you asking score twice? in second system out and for loop of g?

Comment: @jace First question is asking how many test per student. Say there are 3 students and each of them have 3 tests. Hence 3 scores. And then next one is asking what is the score for each of those tests

Comment: oh okay :) let me code for it . thanks for making it clear

Comment: i'm just concern with this. This is useless . Total += Score;

Comment: @jace Oh yes I just noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: I already posted the answer. If you still have concern , just comment there or post another question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageScore {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x; // Number of students
    int y; // Number of tests per student
    int Score = 0; //Score of each test for each student
    double Average = 0; //Average score
    double Total = 0; //Total score
    double Input = 0; **//Add this in your variable**
    boolean Valid = false; **//Add this in your variable**

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of students: ");
        x = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of test scores per student: ");
        y = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int z = 0; z < x; z++)
        {
            System.out.println("Student " + (z + 1));
            System.out.println("------------------------");

            for (int g=0; g < y; g++)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter score " + (g + 1) + ":  ");
                Input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

                //validation of your input from 0 to 100
                if(Input>=0&&Input<=100)
                {
                    Valid = true;
                }

                //enter while loop if not valid
                while(!Valid)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.print("Please enter a valid score " + (g + 1) + ":  ");
                    Input = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                    if(Input>=0&&Input<=100)
                    {
                        Valid = true;
                    }
                }

                Valid = false; //reset validation;

                Total += Input;
                Average = (Total/y);
            }       

            System.out.println("The average score for student " + (z + 1) + " is " + Average);
            System.out.println("                      ");

            Total= 0;
        }

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to go about this would be to put the user-input prompt inside of a while loop, and only break out once you've verified that the grade is valid:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int score;

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter score " + (g + 1) + ":  ");

    score = scanner.nextInt();

    if (score >= 0 && score <= 100) {
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a valid score between 0 and 100!");
}

Total += score;
```

Remember to close your `Scanner`s to avoid memory leaks!

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Oh?  Why would I break out of the loop if the grade isn't valid?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw the condition is right with the break statement, it means to skip when input is correct

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Don't worry about it; it happens to the best of us!